# Redirecting to a remote URL with POST Method, POST Fields and Header Info in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, http-post, guzzle

I've just ran into a situation where i want to POST some data to a remote URL. Apart from **POSTing the data, with some header information, i also want the user to be redirected to that POST url**.

Let me explain the scenario here, I'm integrating a third-party Payment Gateway in my web app. I'm Using **Laravel**. After a chain of API calls, the app is submitting payment details to the API. The API result does have a third-party url (of the respective bank) to which, i need to take the user to complete the authentication process. I have a couple of data and a header info to take along with it. I have tried Laravel Guzzle, but like cURL when we submit the POST data, we'll actually get the response back in our side. But not getting redirected.

If i have to go with a standard html form, how can i post the header information there. Using jQuery ajax could possibly pose the same issue too, that i can't redirect the user.

I have done some re-search and tried something,

1. With guzzle, i'm actually able to show the HTML content back to the user using the getBody method, but the HTML is not getting parsed the right way, the images are broken (because of the relative path they using in there web pages) and the links and buttons are not taking me to the desired locations.

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $transactionResponse['redirectForm']['actionUrl'], [
    'headers' => $transactionResponse['redirectForm']['headers'],
    'form_params' => $transactionResponse['redirectForm']['content']
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

I have tried cURL as well with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION directive, but it too returns the response, not redirecting the user.

```
$post = [
    'username' => 'user1',
    'password' => 'passuser1',
    'gender'   => 1,
];

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/laravel/arax_v1/paytm/callback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'location: http://localhost/laravel/arax_v1/paytm/callback'
));

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);
```

Could anyone have any better idea to work this out ?

Comment: have you tried setting the remote url as action param in the html form? That way, when user clicks submit, they're taken to the remote url and other redirects are handled by the remote server.

Comment: Isn't guzzle much easier for this task?

Comment: @djunehor yeah i've tried that, but how can i then pass header information with it. The remote url looks for data inside the header for further processing.

Comment: @senty I have tried guzzle, and somehow managed to print the response to the DOM.  But it ain't doing any good. The links, buttons and images are all seems broken, as the links are all internal to the remote url and every links are getting mixed up with my domain. Like _remote-url.com/payment/process_ is now pointing to _my-url.com/payment/process_

Comment: Oh, the headers. Can you ask the API provider to return the redirect URL instead of attempting to redirect? That way, you can grab the URL and redirect your user